# How do I save customized state of my java application after it has been closed?

Tags: java, swing

I have created a java application named Test.jar
[image]

with the following interface

[image]

any time when I open Test.jar the checkbox  is unchecked

I want to make this program when a user checkes the checkbox it can save it after I has been closed

this is the code of the program

```
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Test extends JFrame{
    public Test(){
        JPanel p=new JPanel();
        JCheckBox chb=new JCheckBox("save it");
        p.add(chb);
        add(p);
        pack();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test f=new Test();
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Comment: once your program is terminated, it can't do anything anymore. what you can do is: save a txt file, or a properties file, or an xml, with the state of the checkbox. you load this each time you run the app, and update it each time the checkbox is (un)checked

Comment: you have to persist some where [db/file]

Comment: now iam using access database for this. but isnt their another way to do this inside my program internally?

Answer (score 1):

You must save program's state in file or in other persistent storage (windows registry, database etc.) at the exit and load this state at startup.

After loading state, you must manually set `selected` property to loaded value.

Comment: now iam using access database for this.
but isnt their another way to do this inside my program internally?

Answer (score 1):

Use serialization. Persist state of your application before exiting.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a file where you save the user-preferences. For example you can use a property-file and save the current settings in it:

Properties-File-content:

```
saveBox=checked
```

To access that properties-file use `Properties`:

```
// Read properties file.
Properties prop = new Properties();

try {
    prop.load(new FileInputStream("filename.properties"));
} catch (IOException e) {
}


// get the property value of your checkbox
String saveBoxValue= prop.getProperty("saveBox");
```

Then you can check, if the value is for example `checked` or `unchecked`.

To write to the property-file use it like that:

```
// Write properties file.
try {
    props.setProperty("saveBox", "checked");
    prop.store(new FileOutputStream("filename.properties"), null);
} catch (IOException e) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several option to do this. Best practice is to use one of most popular open source library: Apache Commons.
Here you can find an example and all the docs you need.

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide/howto_properties.html

With this library you can able to load, save, and edit a configuration file with your app-preferences.

Hope I helped you

Comment: Do you mean "best practice" or "I recommend"?  If the former, please cite your source for this.  (Hint: in this case there are other approaches that would work just as well.)